# Populate a text field from a bash script

Tags: javascript, html, bash

So I have a webform with a dropdown list, and a field that needs to be populated with the results of a very simple script that takes the option chosen from the dropdown list as imput. (The web server uses apache2 and bash, and a bit of js on the user side. And that is it. Unfortunatelly I can't install anything else on the machine.)

The dropdown menu is automatically populated correctly. 
And when run as a separate bash script the bash function returns what it should.

All the html pieces are inserted on the web page and rendered correctly too.

The problem seems to be because I can't pass the value choseen on the dropdown menu, (processed by the javascript function) to the bash script function.

Any ideas?

There is two text files used as source, one for the dropdown menu:

STUFF.txt:

> eggs
>
> milk
>
> flour

An another for the text field to be populated:

QUANTITY.txt:

> eggs 12unit
>
> milk 6Liters
>
> flour 2Kg

Dropdown:

```
   if [[ "$User" == "$Authorized" ]];then
    echo "<td height=\"30\">$C_STUFF:</td><td colspan=\"3\" align=\"left\" cellpadding=\"0\"><select id=\"STUFF\" name=\"STUFF\" onChange=\"JS_stuff(this.value);\">"
    STUFF=/apache2/cgi-bin/STUFF.txt
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "<option id=\"$line\" name=\"STUFF\" value=\"$line\">$line</option>"
    done < "$STUFF"
    echo "</select>"
    echo "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>"
    fi
```

Text Field:

```
echo "<td></td>
<td>Quantity:</td>
<td colspan=\"3\"><text id=\"quantity\" size=\"15\" type=\"quantity\" name=\"quantity\" value=\"$STUFF\" ></text></td></tr>
```

Javascript function:

```
/****STUFF for the text field**********/
function JS_stuff(sel)
{
    var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML = "";
    return;
 }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML = this.responseText;
 }
 };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getquantity.sh?"+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
```

Bash script & Function:

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./functions.sh
getquantity $QUERY_STRING
```

FUNCTION in functions.sh:

```
 get_stuff_fromlist () {
    STUFF="$QUERY_STRING"
    QUANTITY=/apache2/cgi-bin/QUANTITY.txt
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == $QUERY_STRING* ]] ; then
            printline="yes"
        fi
        if [[ $printline == "yes" ]] ; then
          QUANTITY=  echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'
        fi
        if [[ $line == $QUERY_STRING* ]] ; then
            printline="no"
            echo "$STUFF"
        fi
    done < "$QUANTITY"
    }
```

Comment: a space is missing after `[[`

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks, I typo when formating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, some generic comments.

- I assume the bash script is run as CGI script.
- Generally, interactive web pages with a bash backend is not a good idea for security reason. It's much easier to do some command injection and, as a result, compromise the server. I do not now the reasons why other stuff cannot be installed, but if you had been said  it's because of the security, then you should also avoid processing data fed from browser to server using bash.

As for the problem you mentioned. There are two solutions possible.

Solution 1 - not suitable for bash because of security reasons.

You need to have two scripts. One main script to generate the webform with dropdown. Other one, helper, to receive the stuff as a parameter and return the quantity. So, your javascript `onChange` handler will use  `XMLHttpRequest()` to run the helper script to get the quantity. Welcome in the [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) world. Obvious drawback of this solution is that helper script is fed with data from browser, and the malicious user can spoof the request to provide its own value. In the helper script you need to make sure you won't accidentally run the code provided by such rascal. It's hard in bash, it's easier in other scripting languages.

Solution 2

Prepare your webform in a way it contains a javascript variable being an associative array with stuff and quantities. And `onChange` handler looks up this table and fills quantity appropriately. To develop needed code you can even write a static HTML file with all data encoded. Then, when you're happy with your javascript solution, generate the webpage using CGI script. This solution is good as long, as the amount of stuff is small (the threshold of being small is up to you). It runs on the client side, in browser, and does not make any additional requests to the server.

PS. In dropdown part of the script you are closing the `</select>` tag twice.

Comment: Yes the bash scripts are cgi-scripts, should have mentioned that.

Security is not a problem this is a hobby project reusing a discarded NAS that runs an embebed linux to try and learn how to use javascript and bash.

Took the double </select> out. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So, I would recommend to play with Solution 2 first, then move to Solution 1. Just remember: CGI scripts run on server side. Javascripts run on client side (that means, in browser). Have fun.

Comment: Solution 1: See current scripts on post